# xcode Loading a text string into a UISearchController

Tags: ios, xcode6, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller

I was using this example for searching through a UICollectionView:  https://github.com/ihomam/CollectionViewWithSearchBar/blob/master/collevtionViewWithSearchBar/CollectionViewController.m

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    if (self.searchBarActive) {
        cell.laName.text = self.dataSourceForSearchResult[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.laName.text = self.dataSource[indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

...only my app is setup a little differently:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PlaceCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Place *p = [_entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    if (self.searchBarActive) {
        cell.placeName.text = self.dataSourceForSearchResult[indexPath.item];
    } else {
        cell.placeName.text = p.PName;
        cell.placeImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:p.PImage]]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

So if I just run it the way it is then self.dataSourceForSearchResult[indexpath.item] will return EVERYTHING and I get an error because it's not returning a string...

'`Can't use in/contains operator with collection <Place: 0x17d8ad70> (not a collection)'`

but what I want it to do is search through the p.PName results.  Something like:

```
self.dataSourceForSearchResult[p.PName indexpath.item]
```

Comment: did you try :   shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
  replacementText:(NSString * _Nonnull)text

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Could you elaborate or give me a link to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked through the github code I think that the core of your problem lies somewhere else.

The problem lies here :

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[c] %@", searchText];
    self.dataSourceForSearchResult  = [self.dataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

What this method does is it filters matching items from `self.datasource` (which I assume you renamed to `self.entries`, and I hope you also did it here) based on the predicate. The predicate is a little tricky to understand, especially if you have no previous experience with them. Let's break it down :

- `self` - in this context it means the object that will be checked against the condition. This object will be an element of the array.
- `contains[c]` - this is the condition. The `self` will be checked if it `contains` something. The `[c]` means that the check will be case insensitive.
- `%@` - this is the 'something'. It will be replaced with `searchText`.

This worked in the example because the array contained `NSString` objects and `NSPredicate` knows how to check if they `contain` something (a substring). Since your array consists of `Place` objects the `NSPredicate` doesn't know how to check if they `contain` something (a subplace? :P).

To fix this replace the predicate with this one `self.PName contains[c] %@`. This one will acces the `PName` property of each object of array and check whether it contains the substring.

You can read more on NSPredicate on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/) and in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/)

---

As to the second problem, `self.dataSourceForSearchResult[indexpath.item]` will not in fact return an `NSString` but a `Place` object, though not `EVERYTHING`, but one of the filtered ones. It was actually never reached in your app, as it crashed earlier. No offence, but I think that you don't entirely understand the whole order of things in this code. To break it down :

1. The view controller is shown and the searchbar is empty so the cells are drawn, based on data in `self.datasource` (or `self.entries` as you renamed it). `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is being called.
2. User inputs something in the search bar. (this triggers `searchBar:textDidChange:`).
3. The matching objects are filtered into `self.dataSourceForSearchResult` array.
4. The collection view gets reloaded.
5. The cells are redrawn (`collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is being called again), but since the searchbar is not empty, we now use only objects from `self.dataSourceForSearchResult`.

So to make it work your `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` should look like this :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PlaceCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Place *p;
    // retrieve item from appropriate array
    if (self.searchBarActive) {
        p = self.dataSourceForSearchResult[indexPath.item];
    } else {
        p = self.entries[indexPath.item];
    }

    // populate the cell - we do this regardless of whether the searchbar is active or not
    cell.placeName.text = p.PName;
    cell.placeImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:p.PImage]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Wow... Just... Wow. This was really above and beyond. Thanks.

Comment: I followed your advice and now it works fine. One thing that's baffling me now is that: As I type it does filter the matching object and reloads the collection... but if I backspace it doesn't go back to the original view. Also if I hit the cancel button. It did the very first time I ran the program... but not now. Weirdness... It should be reloading as I delete and it should definitely refresh when I hit the cancel button. (It only changes if I type new text). Do you see any reason why this might be happening?

Comment: Let us follow on chat, as not to clutter the original question : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84280/xcode-loading-a-text-string-into-a-uisearchcontroller-follow-up