# filtering a Json populated UITableView Swift 2

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm trying to filter a JSON populated `UITableView` and so far I have tried 3 or 4 pretty nice tutorials but I am getting the same error on all of them when I press the `SearchBar`.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator
>   with collection MakeItWork.Repository (not a collection'

The only thing that is different from the tutorials I have seen is that my Array is on another file and I am calling it from there.

Repository.swift

```
class Repository {

var name: String?
var releaseDate: String?
var gameImage: String?
var id: String?

init(json: NSDictionary) {
    self.name = json["name"] as? String
    self.releaseDate = json["release_date"] as? String
    self.gameImage = json["image"] as? String
    self.id = json["_id"] as? String
 }
}
```

And the GameTableViewController.swift

```
var games = [Repository]()
var filteredTableData = [String]()
var shouldShowSearchResults = false
var searchController: UISearchController!


func configureSearchController() {
    // Initialize and perform a minimum configuration to the search controller.
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    // Place the search bar view to the tableview headerview.
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text!
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@",searchString)
    let array = (games as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if shouldShowSearchResults {
        return filteredTableData.count
    }
    else {
        return games.count
    }
}

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "GameTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GameTableViewCell

    if (shouldShowSearchResults) {
        cell.nameLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    else {

        cell.nameLabel?.text = games[indexPath.row].name
        cell.releaseDateLabel?.text = games[indexPath.row].releaseDate

        if let url = NSURL(string: self.games[indexPath.row].gameImage!) {
            cell.photoImageView?.hnk_setImageFromURL(url)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

I put a break point at the start of updateSearchResultsForSearchController and I noticed that every time I press the UISearchBar, before the crash, it does a loop of searching with a null searchString since I haven't typed anything inside yet. Is that normal?
Last tutorial I checked was http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift . 
What am I missing here ?

Edit: I think it is normal for the UISearchBar to keep updating all the time as I am calling the `UISearchResultsUpdating`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in your `NSPredicate`. The way it is written you try to check whether objects in `games` array `contain` a string. But the objects in this array are instances of `Repository`, and the predicate has no way to know what it means for `Repository` to contain something. To fix this, you should change your predicate to this :

```
NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name CONTAINS[c] %@",searchString)
```

This way, the predicate will check if the `name` property of `Repository` instance contains the provided search string.

I wrote a tad longer about `NSPredicate` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614712/xcode-loading-a-text-string-into-a-uisearchcontroller/31621322#31621322).

Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Thanks that made me bypass that error but then it crashes on the next line of code with **NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fac5bf7aa60 of class 'MakeItWork.Repository' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[MakeItWork.Repository valueForKey:]** 
I read that if you get that error you need to put :NSObject next to your class and then super.init() inside init(){...}. That gives me another error on the last line saying **fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C**

Comment: Should I make another question for the current errors I am getting and mark this one as answered as your answer solved the problem I mentioned despite the errors that popped up after?

Comment: Well it may be for the best, as more people will notice your new question. And I haven't used 'Swift' much and unfortunatelly don't know how to help you further.